# Class function running out of loop

Tags: c++

I'm working on a bit of code for my class.

I've got the basics of it working, but I've run into an issue while testing the code.

I have an `if` statement that's running the selection for `Yes`, regardless of actual user input. I'm sure it's something small that I'm missing, but I can figure out what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

And I have double checked the brackets in the class `Calendar` that defines those functions.

```
int main()
{
    Calendar adminCal;
    char selection;

    cout << "Would you like to set the date? (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> selection;

    if (selection = 'y' || 'Y')
    {
        adminCal.setDate();
        adminCal.Display();
    }
    else
        adminCal.Display();

return 0;
}
```

### Question:

Why is the `if` statement behaving like this?

Comment: Learn the difference between equal sign and logical equal `=` vs `==`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change

```
if (selection = 'y' || 'Y')
```

to

```
if (selection == 'y' || selection == 'Y')
```

Note that `selection = 'y'` is an assignment operator, not a relation operator which you're expecting. When it's used for an if statement, it will be always `true`, because the char value (it's `y` here) returned by the assignment operator is a nonzero value. And the expression `Y` will be always `true` too.

From the standard, 4.12$1 Boolean conversions [conv.bool]

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer
>   to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero
>   value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
>   to false; any other value is converted to true. For
>   direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.

BTW: Don't ignore the warning messages generated by the compiler, it's trying to help you to find this kind of mistakes. This is the warning message generated by clang:

```
Warning(s):

source_file.cpp:10:25: warning: use of logical '||' with constant operand [-Wconstant-logical-operand]
    if (selection = 'y' || 'Y')
                        ^  ~~~
source_file.cpp:10:25: note: use '|' for a bitwise operation
    if (selection = 'y' || 'Y')
                        ^~
                        |
source_file.cpp:10:19: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
    if (selection = 'y' || 'Y')
        ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
source_file.cpp:10:19: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
    if (selection = 'y' || 'Y')
                  ^
        (                     )
source_file.cpp:10:19: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
    if (selection = 'y' || 'Y')
                  ^
                  ==
2 warnings generated.
```

Comment: I knew it was something small I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: @Rannof BTW, most compiler will compain it by giving warning messages, develop  the habit not to ignore them will save your time much.